# How to get all registered user from Openfire through http

Tags: xmpp, openfire, smack

I am trying to make Simple Openfire plugin.I have an ArrayList of usersnames which are phone numbers, i want all the registered users from it.The ArrayList want to send the ArrayList to server by json throung get or post method ,But i donot know how my plugin can listen for that request and respond to that user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific requirement you should check [Openfire Rest-API Plugin](https://www.igniterealtime.org/projects/openfire/plugins/restapi/readme.html).

The plugin already provides Users related operations over HTTP, like: Get overview over all or specific user and to create, update or delete a user.

So you can request all registered users in Openfire or You can query for a specific user if it's already registered or not. And it also supports authentication so your http endpoints will be secure.

Examples:

GET http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users 
GET http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users?search=testuser 
GET http://example.org:9090/plugins/restapi/v1/users/testuser

Regarding new plugin development, I would suggest you to start with Rest-API, it's already opensource, you can checkout the code and customize it as per your business needs or you can use it to develop your own plugin following it's project structure.

There is also a client library available as [Rest-API Client](https://github.com/igniterealtime/REST-API-Client).

Comment: yaaa... i can make the plugin for opefire.. and already check out the restApi but donot know how the dns resolve in it... how to point my code on a particular dns..how to response back to user

Comment: If Openfire server is already running on your server and you are able to access it's admin console on port 9090, then what's the issue of DNS?

Comment: yes...but there is little bit confusion .. when we visit on a site example. com/test/test.php , there is a test.php page exists which give the response on echo...but in restApi there is no page or directory  like rest/v1/user .. so how it handle the request... how openfire route the request

Comment: The plugin is using Java Restful Services (JAX-RS) annotations and these are added in java code so the controller is directly receiving the request as per registered url and after processing it writes JSON response.